# SQL join query using rows which only have date of today to sort

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sure this is really simple... just tired now.

I have a query

```
SELECT post.*, votes.datetime, COUNT(votes.post_id) AS votes        
FROM posts LEFT JOIN votes          
ON posts.id = votes.post_id         
GROUP BY posts.id       
ORDER BY votes DESC
```

I need to fetch **all** posts on the left table whilst when counting votes on the votes table using the votes which happened **today** or between 1 hour and another hour of the same day. Does this make enough sense?

I have tried adding

```
WHERE DATE(votes.datetime) = DATE(NOW())
```

But no luck, it just shows the rows which have votes which happened today and no other posts rows which have either no votes at all or votes that happened today.

I am using data type `datetime` for the datetime column

Any ideas how I can do this easily?

Thanks in advance!

-Stefan

Comment: How about trying a WHERE clause, instead of using AND on your LEFT JOIN condition? or maybe make a subquery, ie. instead of LEFT JOIN votes, LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM votes WHERE...)

Comment: sorry it was a WHERE clause just I hd deleted some other lines and the was AND due to this... editing! thanks - Sub query may work, speed be affected much??

Comment: oh right i see, no, not really, you can optimise for performance later, by converting it to an equivalent SQL query that doesn't use subqueries when you're sober.

Comment: @evandrix that worked a treat as a sub query! thanks very much for this. I'm sure this will work for just now until as you say "i'm sober" :) thanks again!

Comment: right, i'll post it as an answer and you can close it. i'm certain almost all SQL queries containing subqueries can be converted to a similar one which does not do so. remember being given an exercise on it to complete before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery in your LEFT JOIN votes expression, specifying the condition you seek as a WHERE clause within this. Then later, if necessary, optimise for performance by transforming away the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM votes WHERE DATE(datetime) = DATE(NOW())) votes
```

I suspect this won't give you what you want, since `SELECT ... votes.datetime ...` will result in each post being listed multiple times, and `COUNT(votes.post_id)` almost always evaluating to 1.

Unfortunately, I can't grok exactly what you need from your question. (What does "... between 1 hour and another hour of the same day" mean? Also, you can't order by votes.) If you just want a count of today's votes for all posts, you can do this:

```
SELECT posts.id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM votes
         WHERE DATE(datetime) = DATE(NOW())
           AND post_id = posts.id
       ) AS num_votes
FROM posts
```

Comment: Oh so close but this is also correct! Thanks for the contribution!

Comment: As in I may want votes between 3am and 3am of a given day rather than from 00:00:00 from one day to another. Does this make sense? I can run a group by COUNT(votes.post_id) as Votes it seems to work it's just when adding the DATE(datetime) part then it drops the posts that dont have votes

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if I understand your problem correctly, but the way I understand it I would suggest usinf `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`.

This way you get all the posts, even those without votes.

```
SELECT post.*, votes.datetime, COUNT(votes.post_id) AS votes        
FROM posts LEFT OUTER JOIN votes          
ON posts.id = votes.post_id         
WHERE DATE(votes.datetime) = DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY posts.id       
ORDER BY votes DESC
```